# How call and execute a method present in a .dll file and show your (s) Form (s)?

Tags: delphi, dll

I had that imported a Form already made for a .dll file, and now want call this Form from of my .exe software and open he normally on .dll file.

This is all that have until now, but nothing works :-(

***Dll file with a Form inside***

```
library test;


uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Winapi.Windows,
  UMyForm, // Reference to my Form (traditional VCL Form)
  System.Classes,
  StrUtils;

{$R *.res}

var
HProcess: THandle;
Hid: Cardinal;
b: Boolean = False;

procedure Call;
begin
  MyForm := TMyForm.Create(nil);
  MyForm.ShowModal;
 end;
end;

begin

 HProcess:= OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,False,GetCurrentProcessId);
 CreateRemoteThread(HProcess,nil,0,@call,@call,0,Hid);

end.
```

***My software that call and open the Form of Dll file***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 LoadLibraryA(PAnsiChar('test.dll'));
end;

end.
```

Comment: @MartynA, How to call `Call` method from of my software and show the Form that is present on .dll file? This is my main goal.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've tried googling "delphi call dll procedure"

Comment: None of the code you've presented makes any effort to execute the *Call* procedure in your DLL, and your *CreateRemoteThread* call is meaningless (the callback has to meet a specific criteria, and it can't directly interact with GUI elements, so it won't work anyway - all interaction with VCL controls has to take place in the main thread, not some thread you've created randomly).

Comment: This code is complete nonsense. It is implemented badly. Doesn't do anything sensible. Doesn't meet interface contracts. Doesn't carry out error checking. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I want execute the `Call` method in dll file and show `TMyForm` that is associated to dll like you can see above. Can you give me a example of code about how do this correctly?

Comment: It makes no sense. You are passing the current process ID. You ignored all my other points too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, is possible make this that I want? `Call a method present in a .dll file and show any VCL Form created in this .dll`

Comment: Your code doesn't attempt to do that. You don't attempt to load a DLL. And what about the VCL threading rules? Why are you neglecting error checking. It seems like you think programming can be done without adhering to the rules.

Comment: Your call to CreateRemoteThread makes no sense whatsoever. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

VCL has limitations:

- All forms have to be running in main thread of the application;
- Forms can be in Dlls **only** if you build both Exe and Dll with run-time packages in the same version of Delphi.

If you can't meet this limitations, than you should create windows in Dll without VCL. For example in pure WinAPI or with a help from [KOL](http://kolmck.net/) (somewhere should be port to newer versions of Delphi). Another option is to use scripting engines like [DWScript](https://www.delphitools.info/dwscript/): you embed scripting engine in main Exe. Then your Dll exports a function that returns script text. This script creates necessary forms and processes all events itself or links them to functions inside Dll. This way you will meet all limitations of the VCL.

Comment: It is possible to put forms in DLLs. What's tricky is the interaction with other forms in the process. A good example of where you might have forms in a DLL is an Office COM add-in. That can be perfectly well implemented without runtime packages.

Comment: Forms in Dll sort of work, but I newer managed to force them work **reliably**. Every time I thought that now everything will be OK, I have encountered a situation, when small innocent change on form causes big new bugs.

Comment: They can work reliably if you stick to a rigid set of rules. Anyway, there's really a lot more wrong with the code in the question. Looks like asker is trying to inject into a process. If the injected thread runs its own message loop there's no reason why it can't show UI. Of course, how that interacts with the rest of the UI in the victim process is anybody's guess.